# Replace the usage of gets with getchar

Tags: c, getchar, gets

I currently have a homework assignment and I used `gets`.
The professor said I should be using `getchar` instead.

What is the difference?

How would I change my code to use `getchar`? I can't seem to get it right.

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#define STORAGE 255

int main() {
  int c;
  char s[STORAGE];

  for(;;) {
    (void) printf("n=%d, s=[%s]\n", c = getword(s), s);
    if (c == -1) break;
  }
}

int getword(char *w) {
  char str[255];
  int i = 0;
  int charCount = 0;

  printf("enter your sentence:\n");   //user input
  gets(str);

  for(i = 0; str[i] != '\0' && str[i] !=EOF; i++){
    if(str[i] != ' '){
      charCount++;
    } else {
      str[i] = '\0'; //Terminate str
      i = -1; //idk what this is even doing?
      break;      //Break out of the for-loop
    }
  }

  printf("your string: '%s' contains %d of letters\n", str, charCount); //output
  strcpy(w, str);

  //    return charCount;
  return strlen(w); //not sure what i should be returning.... they both work
}
```

Comment: Please edit your post and fix indention and code formatting.

Comment: Main difference is that there is no function called `gets` in the C language. It was removed 5 years ago and flagged for obsolescence 17 years ago.

Comment: It depends what you're trying to do, but `getchar()` is not usually a preferred replacement for `gets()`.   `fgets()` is preferred - since it can be used to read a line, but can also be used in safe ways, unlike `gets()`.

Answer (score 2):

`gets()` *was supposed* to get a *string* from the input and store it into the supplied argument. However, due to lack of preliminary validation on the input length, it is vulnerable to buffer overflow.

A better choice is [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets).

However, coming to the usage of [`getchar()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar) part, it reads one `char` at a time. So basically, you have to keep reading from the standard input one by one, using a loop, until you reach a newline (or EOF) which marks the end of expected input.

As you read a character (with optional validation), you can keep on storing them in `str` so that, when the input loop ends, you have the input string ready in `str`.

Don't forget to null terminate `str`, just in case.